# How to achieve the effect (shown in the attached image) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve the following effect in a div box. What CSS would do the trick? Thank you in advance for your answers!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the linear-gradient function in CSS3, the code will be +- like this:

```
.box{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, blue, white, blue)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I would like to use RGB values instead of literal color names?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 with [linear gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). Something like this:

```css
.demo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.gradient {
  background: #508cf4; /* Old browsers for fallback */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #508cf4 0%, #ffffff 50%, #508cf4 100%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient demo"></div>
```

You could also google for "css3 gradient generator" to have a GUI. For example [cssgradient.io](https://cssgradient.io/)

Comment: thank you! Accepted Eric's answer above because he commented the earliest. :)

Answer (score 2):

as stated in the first answer, use css gradients, and combine with border-radius for your rounded corners.

```css
.box{
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #4690ff, #ffffff, #4690ff);
    border-radius:15px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: thank you! Accepted Eric's answer above because he commented the earliest. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might test run a few css gradient tools like [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/) and [GradientFinder](http://gradientfinder.com/) to work with gradient colors.

Also, by combining a low opacity radial gradient with a linear gradient you can get a more rich look that might get closer to your original image.

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 182px;
  height: 229px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(252,253,255,.2) 54%,rgba(212,229,255,.2) 66%,rgba(212,229,255,.2) 66%,rgba(153,193,255,.2) 79%,rgba(153,193,255,.2) 79%,rgba(57,136,255,.2) 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to top, rgb(57, 136, 255) 0%, rgb(153, 193, 255) 13%, rgb(212, 229, 255) 23%, rgb(252, 253, 255) 43%, rgb(252, 253, 255) 57%, rgb(212, 229, 255) 77%, rgb(153, 193, 255) 87%, rgb(57, 136, 255) 100%);
  border-radius: 16px 0 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<p>original <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ5Z6.png" /></p>
```